# Mysql JOIN subquery

Tags: mysql, join

How should I do query where

- I have (table1) row which can have none or several rows referencing to it in other table
- These referencing (table2) rows have colum1 that can be null or date

I would like to have all rows from table1 which have all rows column1 not as null or no rows at all, in table2.

Of course the basic sql goes like:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.table2_id
```

But what comes next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the occurences of null in your query like `SUM(CASE WHEN table2.col IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nullcount`, i assume `table2.col` is the one which has date of null in it

```
SELECT 
  table1.*,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN table2.col IS NULL 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS nullcount 
FROM
  table1 
  JOIN table2 
    ON table2.id = table1.table2_id 
HAVING nullcount > 0
```

Comment: @AngularAddict see [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdd4e/5) there is difference between where and having

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But how can get also c_contact row with id=2 as it has no references in c_monitoring. Actually what I want is rows from c_contact that has no rows in c_cmonitoring or all c_monitoring ended rows are dates, not nulls. Updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7b17/4

Comment: @AngularAddict see [second query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7b17/10) i have added the one more condition in on clause and the row which has 0 null dates are there first query is just to show the data set

Comment: Ok. Updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e97cf/2 This quite correct but also c_contact rows with no references in c_monitoring table should be in result set.

Comment: Nailed it by myself with different approach. See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e97cf/22

Comment: @AngularAddict i guess i got you try this [union fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e97cf/21) it has the records where dates are not null with a union where no reference is found let me know it this fits

Comment: But I have to say this is so slow. I have about 100.000 records in c_contact and 10.000 in c_monitoring.. Ill just start another thread for this.

Comment: @AngularAddict try your query with [*exists fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e97cf/24) Not in is also makes your query slow

Comment: @AngularAddict add these two indexes if you have not added already ALTER TABLE `c_contact` ADD INDEX `test` (`securityid`); 
ALTER TABLE `c_monitoring` ADD INDEX `test1` (`securityid`);