# How to optimize "WHERE NOT IN" with subquery

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery, notin

I have this query what was discussion output in this thread: [Mysql JOIN subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108999/mysql-join-subquery)

See current fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e97cf/22

```
create table c_contact 
(id INT, 
 name VARCHAR(20), 
 securityid INT
);

create table c_monitoring 
(started DATE, 
 ended DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
 securityid INT
);


SELECT
  c_contact.id,
  c_contact.name,
  c_contact.securityid
FROM c_contact
WHERE c_contact.securityid != ''
  AND c_contact.securityid NOT IN
      (select securityid 
       from c_monitoring 
       where ended is null 
       group by securityid
      )
GROUP BY c_contact.id ;
```

How the hell I am going to optimize this query? I have 100.000 records in c_contact table and about 10.000 in c_monitoring table. Query takes > 30 secs with 127 result rows.

**EDIT: Case was solved by indexing tables correctly.**

Comment: If you solved the problem, add the solution (the indexes used) as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has some group by problems (actually, you should not have any group by clauses), and you should convert it to a join:

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.name,
  c.securityid
FROM c_contact c
LEFT JOIN c_monitoring m ON m.securityid = c.securityid
  AND m.ended is null
WHERE c.securityid != ''
AND m.securityid IS NULL
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e97cf/34)

I also tidied up the query a little with aliases.

Comment: @AngularAddict Huh? I got 2 rows. Are you sure you've refreshed the page? This is the fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e97cf/34

Comment: Quess I had cached page. Works. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Case was solved by indexing table fields

- c_contact.securityid
- c_monitoring.started
- c_monitoring.ended
- c_monitoring.securityid

Query takes now ~200ms